# Obfuscate Latex command

Tags: tex-general

Say I have a series of commands in my latex source `\command1{blabla}`, `\command2{blublu}`, etc...

Is there a way to obfuscate these commands, so to maintain their behaviour but hide the actual name?

Comment: You can call them what you like, but if you really want obscure code I suggest you stick to plain and read `xii.tex`!

Comment: `\let\mysuperstrangenamewhichhidestheactualname\commandone` for example. You could do a `\def` or a `\renewcommand` but `\let` is the quickest way, but I don't recommend it

Comment: It depends on the reason for obfuscation, you can always go \let\zzzzzzz\section and then use \zzzzzzz instead of \section if you wish but it is not hiding anything any user can go \show\zzzzzzz and see the definition of that command.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That's true, but the 'standard' user of `LaTeX` does not know/use `\show` or will have a look into the defining `.sty` or `.cls` file.

Comment: I've considered solutions like `\let` or `\def`, but the problem is that "command1" will still appear in the source, hence it will be evident that I've used it. Which is what I'm trying to hide.

Comment: @FilippoBistaffa: I don't get the point: Why is it 'bad' if anybody recognizes `\command1` being used in your document?

Comment: At the end of the day, you can always track things back to source. After all, we are only doing expansion.

Comment: Hey! I believe we know each other! `;-)`

Comment: I don't think "why I want to do this" is relevant... I just need the strings "command1", "command2" not to appear in my source...

Comment: @FilippoBistaffa It's still not clear to me why you can't just change the names of the commands to something else.

Comment: @FilippoBistaffa Define your renamed commands in external files (.cls, .sty as already mentioned, or `\input{}` in the preamble a .tex file) but do not share this files. In any other case, no matter how much obscured is your code, someone can do a reverse engineering.

Comment: Wait. You mean LaTeX isn't obfuscated already? Now I feel inadequate all over again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
\lccode`A=`s \lccode`B=`e \lccode`C=`c 
\lccode`D=`t \lccode`E=`i \lccode`F=`o
\lccode`G=`n
\lowercase{\endgroup\expandafter\let\expandafter\ZZZ\csname ABCDEFG\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\ZZZ{A section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: brilliant! Actually I was thinking of an approach like this, but I lack the skills to actually implement it :)

Comment: @FilippoBistaffa I don't think I covered it in my course. `;-)`

Answer (score 14):

```
\^^64o^^63^^75^^6d^^65nt^^63l^^61ss{^^61rt^^69^^63l^^65}

\^^62^^65g^^69^^6e{^^64oc^^75^^6d^^65nt}

\s^^65^^63t^^69o^^6e{^^65x^^61^^6dpl^^65}

O^^6e^^63^^65 ^^75po^^6e ^^61 t^^69^^6d^^65

\^^65^^6e^^64{^^64oc^^75^^6d^^65nt}
```

Comment: Real Programmers don't use ...LaT... assem ..machin.... ehhh ... what is this.

Comment: @Fran it's latex

Comment: Once upon a time (ten minutes ago) I thought I knew something of LaTeX `:)`

Comment: I see a feature request for [recode](http://recode.progiciels-bpi.ca/). :-)